# Header Auth is not send in Swagger Laravel

Tags: laravel, swagger

I am using laravel 9 and swagger and I installed the DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger package.

In swagger config I added:

```
'securityDefinitions' => [
            'securitySchemes' => [
                'api_key_security' => [ // Unique name of security
                    'type' => 'apiKey', // The type of the security scheme. Valid values are "basic", "apiKey" or "oauth2".
                    'description' => 'A short description for security scheme',
                    'name' => 'x-session-id', // The name of the header or query parameter to be used.
                    'in' => 'header', // The location of the API key. Valid values are "query" or "header".
                ],
            ],
            'security' => [
                [
                    'api_key_security' => []
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

and in function definition inside the controller I need to use the x-session-id header:

```
/**
     * Create TEST
     * @OA\Get (
     *     path="/api/test",
     *     tags={"test"},
     *     summary="Endpoint de prueba",
     *     security={
     *       {"api_key_security":{}}
     *     },
     *     @OA\RequestBody(
     *         @OA\MediaType(
     *             mediaType="application/json"
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="success",
     *     ),
     * )
     */
    public function index(): ?string
```

I saw in internet that adding the security key it should works but when I send the request in swagger the header 'x-session-id' is not added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use headers parameter in the response body like this

- ```
      @OA\Header(
  ```

  - ```
            header="X-Rate-Limit",
    ```
  - ```
            description="calls per hour allowed by the user",
    ```
  - ```
            @OA\Schema(
    ```
  - ```
                type="integer",
    ```
  - ```
                format="int32"
    ```
  - ```
            )
    ```
  - ```
        ),
    ```